# Add plugins option missing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site. In the plugins tab, the "Add New" plugin option is missing.
[image]

Even hovering over the plugin tab doesn't produce in drop-menu options.

I was suggested the issue could be the result of me not being provided with administrative rights, but I'm the only user and I do have administrative rights.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see your add new plugin button, the issue could be

- Your theme prevents you from seeing it
- You don't have the permissions to add new plugins.
- You have a corrupted WordPress installation
- A plugin is hiding the button (likely unintentionally)

If you are certain that your user has administrator rights (which you can check in under users in the left navigation bar) try to select a different theme and see if the button becomes available to you again.

Otherwise you might be looking at a complete reinstall of WordPress on your site.

Comment: will reinstalling or changing theme remove any content?

Comment: No, changing theme doesn't touch the content itself. And if you just change theme you can always revert to the previous theme if that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: There are other potential explanations: a wp-config directive disables directory file editing, or you have a corrupted WP install and need to reinstall core files, or a plugin conflict, or, or, or.

Comment: @WorksforaLiving Thanks for the feedback - I've included it in the answer. I don't really see how disabling directory file editing would hide the "Add New" button - it would just fail once you try to install a plugin I imagine?